apt-get -f install returns with "E: Encountered a section with no Package: header"
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
The troubles started when after reboot the teamviewer didn't start anymore. I tried to start manually, getting errormsg, that the teamviewer daemon doesn't run and I should start it by
teamviewer daemon start
sudo apt-get install -f

This failed with a couple of other msgs.
I tried another reboot of the system and then to fix this with $ sudo apt-get install -f.
These are the errormsgs:
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fehler!
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header 
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: Die Paketliste oder die Statusdatei konnte nicht eingelesen oder geöffnet werden.

To fix this, I tried
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update

but again, already on the second line with apt-get install -f, I get the same error.
In another thread was proposed to remove the problematic mergelist, so I tried
sudo rm var/lib/dpkg/status

but this returned with

rm: das Entfernen von 'var/lib/dpkg/status' ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`


sudo rm var/lib/dpkg/status should have a leading / -> /var/lib/dpkg/status ... note that it is missing in your error message.

The missing slash / may have some crucial impact on your endeavor.

Thanks for this hint. This did it. All commands (sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/status; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get update ) run without error-msg. - Not yet clear if this solved the problem with the teamviewer.

Restore the dpkg status file from backup if you have one: https://askubuntu.com/a/136403/158442. If not, consider reinstalling as the dpkg status file is crucial for package management
